iTerm2 send tmux command keymapping action doesn't work
I'm trying to set a key mapping for ⌘ + shift + arrow keys to switch between panes in tmux.
I have created a keymapping in iTerm2.
Shortcut ⌘ shift < with the action send tmux command select-pane -L does not seem to work. I'm not quite sure why.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, I would like to switch the panes based on my key mapping instead of ctrl + b + arrow key. My mapping is not working.
